# Close fragments on button click and return result?

Tags: android, android-fragments

On a click of a button within a fragment, is it possible to close the two fragments within the same activity and return the result of the fragment to another activity? One fragment is expecting input while the other fragment has information for the user to view and is not expecting input.

Also, my code worked prior to using fragments in the activity, however the fragments are no longer showing up when clicking the intent to go to the activity (NextActivity.class) that holds the fragments...does any happen to know why the fragments are not appearing?

Here is some of my code below

A piece from the original activity:

```
    public class MessageList extends ListActivity {

    private void createMessage() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE); //this line is incorrect, right?
    }}
```

Here is a snippet from a fragment class:

```
        public class MessageEditorFragment extends Fragment {

        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }}
```

Also here is the activity class that holds the fragments, just incase you want a look:

```
    public class NextActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab one = actionBar.newTab().setText("Message Editor");
    Tab two = actionBar.newTab().setText("Information");

    one.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(new MessageEditorFragment()));
    two.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(new InformationFragment()));

    actionBar.addTab(one);
    actionBar.addTab(two);
    }
    public class MyTabListener implements TabListener{
    Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabListener(Fragment f){
        fragment = f;
    }}}
```

I deeply appreciate all and any help!! Please let me know if you need to see more code as well.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

When the `Activity` is destroyed by calling `finish` , both the `fragments` will be `destroyed/closed`.

So, Before you `finish` the `Activity` from fragment, you can pass the values to the `Activity` which started it.

When you start the `Activity` , You need to start the `Activity` for `Result` , to return back the result data from the `Fragment/Activity`

In your `Activity` declare a integer request code

```
 int FRAGMENT_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
```

Start the activity , as per your logic

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivityEx.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, FRAGMENT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Add a callback method `onActivityResult` to receive the result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == FRAGMENT_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText(data.getExtras().getString("DATA"));
        }
    }
}
```

Now. In your Fragment, When you close the two `Fragments` , You can pass the data back to the caller `Activity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("DATA","Hai");
getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Hmm, for some strange reason, I still cannot get the fragment to display...However it's a step in the right direction because it is no longer crashing. Right now when I click to add a new message, the list activity is called again. Any ideas?? Should I provide more code? And If so, in what file(s)?

Comment: It could be different issue, I would suggest to create a new question

Comment: Yes you're right, thanks I will. I will try your code again once I figure out this other problem